# Can googleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this) & googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this) be used at same time?

Tags: android, google-maps

Basically i was trying to use both drag and long click feature in android map.
I was successfully able to drag the marker but as soon as i use the long press on map ,Drag feature stops working. and every time long click on map is working.
can any one help me on why it is behaving like this.?

Comment: So you're saying that after you long press on the map, you're no longer able to drag the marker? Can you provide some code or an example that demonstrates your issue?